# Getting error while importing customers in Magento community

Tags: magento, csv

I am getting this error while importing customers in the community version of Magento. There is no such column like 'reward_update_notification' and 'reward_warning_notification'.

Required attribute 'reward_update_notification' has an empty value in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Required attribute 'reward_warning_notification' has an empty value in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Magento version is 1.9.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is causing the problem. When you export new customers the column is there but the fields are empty.

Add the columns (with field names on line 1) and fill them with "1"

it works.
Erik